# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, odbc

**I GOT THIS ERROR at   Da.Fill(Ds, "tbl_user") :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
**

```
Public Conn As OdbcConnection
    Public Da As OdbcDataAdapter
    Public Ds As DataSet
    Public Dr As OdbcDataReader
    Public CMD As OdbcCommand

    Public MyDB As String


    Public Sub Connection()
        MyDB = "Driver={Mysql ODBC 5.1 driver};database=uas;server=localhost;uid=root"
        Conn = New OdbcConnection(MyDB)
        'jika koneksinya tertutup maka akan di open
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Conn.Open()
    End Sub
```

```
 Private Sub FormMasterAdmin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call closeField()
        Call Connection()
        Da = New OdbcDataAdapter("Select username,fullname,level From tbl_user", Conn)
        Ds = New DataSet
        Da.Fill(Ds, "tbl_user")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables("tbl_user")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're using ODBC instead of the dedicated MySQL ADO.NET provider?

Comment: What's the point of checking whether a connection that you only just created is open or closed? How could it possibly be open? This suggests that you're not really thinking about the steps you're performing and are probably just copying or reproducing chunks of code without really understanding what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your code file add...

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

The `Call` keyword is only used in special circumstances. It is usually not necessary.

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. Database objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you. In this code both the connection and the command are included in the `Using` block. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the Using.

```
Private MyDB As String = "Driver={Mysql ODBC 5.1 driver};database=uas;server=localhost;uid=root"

Private Sub FormMasterAdmin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(MyDB),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select username, fullname, level From tbl_user", Conn)
        Conn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

You will have to correct the connection string to the format required by the MySql provider. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/